# AppendAllText writing garbage

Tags: c#, ssis

I have the following in a SSIS Script Task:

However, when I view the output text file, I get a string of garbage characters.

```
public void Main()
{

    string variableValue = Dts.Variables["Failure_Reason"].Value.ToString();
    string outputFile = Dts.Variables["ErrorLog"].Value.ToString();

    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(outputFile, variableValue);


    // TODO: Add your code here
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

When I put a breakpoint in the script, I see the correct information:

> "There was a failure looking up the Job Number.\r\nThe item that
>   caused the failure was: \r\nLine: D\r\nQuantity: 1\r\nFootage:
>   1.166667\r\n"

I've tried changing the encoding to UTF-8 and ASCII, but I still get garbage. Any reason why?

Comment: Are you implying that the `\r\n` are the garbage characters? Do you notice any pattern to the error message and the presence of the "garbage"? What if you ran whatever loads `Failure_Reason` outside of SSIS from the command line, what does that look like?

Comment: No, I am not implying `\r\n` are garbage characters. I'm implying that `桔牥⁥慷⁳⁡慦汩牵⁥潬歯湩⁧灵琠敨䨠扯丠浵敢⹲਍桔⁥瑩浥琠慨⁴慣獵摥琠敨映楡畬敲眠獡›਍楌敮›ൄ儊慵瑮瑩㩹ㄠ਍潆瑯条㩥ㄠㄮ㘶㘶ഷ` are garbage. I have the `Failure_Reason` emailed to me currently, and I see the correct information. But, because this task will be run often, I do not want it clogging up the email but rather check an error log at the end of each day.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. I suspect you've either over simplified the problem, your initial log has funky or unicode data in it or the process that populates `Failure_Reason` has a BOM or something like that. Nuke log file from orbit and try a fresh run.

My package looks like

[image: control flow]

Results

[image]

Text output

[image]

### Biml

Biml, the business intelligence markup language, allows me to use a bit of XML to define what an SSIS package should look like and then you, the reader can use it at home to reproduce my results. This saves me the trouble of taking a few hundred screenshots and you the trouble of getting every nook and cranny configured correctly.

All you need to do is install the free, open source, add-on for visual studio/bids/SSDT called [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com)

Once installed, you will right click on your existing SSIS project and select "Add New Biml file"

Into the contents of the newly created BimlScript.biml, paste the following code (minor modifications required for 2005/2008).

Right click on the biml file and choose Generate SSIS Package. At this point, you should have the above package and can watch it create a log file in C:\ssisdata unless you change line 90 below

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <ScriptProjects>
        <ScriptTaskProject ProjectCoreName="ST_32983202" Name="ST_32983202" VstaMajorVersion="0">
            <ReadOnlyVariables>
                <Variable Namespace="User" VariableName="Failure_Reason" DataType="String" />
                <Variable Namespace="User" VariableName="ErrorLog" DataType="String" />
            </ReadOnlyVariables>
            <Files>
                <File Path="ScriptMain.cs" BuildAction="Compile">using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ST_32983202
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            bool fireAgain = false;

            string variableValue = Dts.Variables["Failure_Reason"].Value.ToString();
            string outputFile = Dts.Variables["ErrorLog"].Value.ToString();
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(outputFile, variableValue);

            string message = variableValue;
            Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "variableValue", message, string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
    }
}               </File>
                <File Path="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" BuildAction="Compile">
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

//
// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
//
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("AssemblyTitle")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("ProductName")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright @  2015")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
//
// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Revision and Build Numbers
// by using the '*' as shown below:

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
                </File>
            </Files>
            <AssemblyReferences>
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Data" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Windows.Forms" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Xml" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask.dll" />
            </AssemblyReferences>
        </ScriptTaskProject>
    </ScriptProjects>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="so_32983202" ConstraintMode="Linear">
            <Variables>
                <Variable DataType="String" Name="Failure_Reason"><![CDATA[There was a failure looking up the Job Number.
The item that caused the failure was: 
Line: D
Quantity: 1
Footage: 1.166667
]]></Variable>
                <Variable DataType="String" Name="ErrorLog">C:\ssisdata\so_32983202.log</Variable>
            </Variables>
            <Tasks>
                <Script ProjectCoreName="ST_32983202" Name="SCR Do Stuff">
                    <ScriptTaskProjectReference ScriptTaskProjectName="ST_32983202" />
                </Script>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```